Container of std::variant of callable objects with bound parameters w/o using dynamic memory
I want to store several different callable objects (different types) in a container (e.g. std::array) in order to invoke them later.
Each callable has the same return type and the same amount and type of parameters: for example, let's say all those objects can be invoked like int func(void *). However, they contain a varying amount of (possibly many) parameters (of only fundamental type) bound to different functions per callable type.
The question is: what is the recommended C++ (C++23) way of implementing this, while avoiding dynamic memory allocations due to the required storage for the bound function parameters in the callable?
Example implementation with std::function:
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

int foo(int, void *);
int bar(char, double, void *);

int i; char c; double d;

auto callable_foo = std::function{[=](void *p){ return foo(i, p); } // binds i
auto callable_bar = std::function{[=](void *p){ return foo(c, d, p); } // binds c and d

using variant_t = std::variant<decltype(callable_foo), decltype(callable_bar)>;

std::array<variant_t, 2> container{callable_foo, callable_bar};

I am aware that in this case, a std::variant is not even required since an array of adequate std::functions would be okay. Nevertheless (as far as I know), std::functions have limited storage for bound function parameters and, at some point, may require dynamic memory allocation. Same is true for lambdas (if I am not mistaken) when you store them in a container (or std::function), even if the capture is only by value of fundamental types.
After searching and experimenting a lot, I basically found two promising solutions:

using a std::variant of std::binds (e.g. auto callable_foo = std::bind(foo, i, _1); instead)
using a C-style solution with a custom data type per callable, containing the function pointer and bound parameters

To summarize my questions:

are there other solutions besides (1) and (2), avoiding dynamic memory allocation?
the return type of std::bind seems to be not assignable (copy and move, at least in my case). How can I put objects returned by std::bind into a std::array<std::variant<WrapperType1, WrapperType2, ..., WrapperTypeN>>, where each WrapperType has a data member of type decltype(std::bind(...))?

Solution (2) will clearly work, but it does not seem like the C++ way of doing this, and I hope the language allows for a cleaner way.
My favorite "I wish" solution was using a template specialization of std::function, allowing to set the SSO storage size such that all bound parameters (size determined at compile-time) fit into the std::function object.
I searched on google, asked ChatGPT, read several pages on cppreference, experimented with actual code, and asked colleagues.

Do you need type-erasure? Do you have lifetime guaranty of the captures?

@Jarod42 What exactly do you mean by type erasure in this context? The arguments are captured by value. Thus there is no lifetime issue:
If the lambda expression captures anything by copy [...] the closure type includes unnamed non-static data members [...] that hold copies of all entities that were so captured. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Type-erasure via std::function. and for lifetime, I talked about the lambda, as "when the target is a function pointer or a std::reference_wrapper, small object optimization is guaranteed". so std::reference_wrapper guarantees no allocation, but requires lifetime of that reference.

Well the lambda type might not be available where I need to declare the container (array), because it's declaration must be in a different scope. I should have stated this in the question explicitly. Thus, I think I need something like type-erasure. The bound parameters are really just copies of fundamental types. References would not work for my use case anyway.

Lambdas are not std::functions.  std::functions store copyable and invokable objects of any type and expose those operations.  To do this, they rely on possibly dynamic allocation for their storage.
std::variant will not use dynamic allocation if its content types don't.
Lambda's won't use dynamic allocations if the capture contents don't.
auto callable_foo = [=](void *p){ return foo(i, p); // binds i
auto callable_bar = [=](void *p){ return foo(c, d, p); // binds c and d

by stripping out the std::function we remove dynamic allocation here.
using variant_t = std::variant<decltype(callable_foo), decltype(callable_bar)>;

a downside to using a variant_t here is that each element requires as much space as every other element, plus an index field.  So if one of them is much larger than the others, you waste space.  But:
std::array<variant_t, 2> container{callable_foo, callable_bar};

should work.  Calling it is a bit annoying, because you need to use std::visit.
int retval = std::visit( [&pvoid](auto& f){ return f(pvoid); }, container[0] );

you can fix that with a thin wrapper
struct callable:variant_t {
  using variant_t::variant_t;

  int operator()(void* pv)const {
    return std::visit( [&pvoid](auto& f){ return f(pvoid); }, (variant_t const&)*this );
  }
};
std::array<callable, 2> container{callable_foo, callable_bar};

again, no dynamic memory overhead (or any extra here).

You can make things a bit more efficient by combining a structure with an array of function-view types.
struct Callables {
  callable_foo foo;
  callable_bar bar;
  // etc
};

struct helper {
  void* pCallable;
  int(*pfunc)(void*, void*);
  int operator()(void* pv)const {
    return pfunc(pCallable, pv);
  }

  template<class T>
  helper( T* t ):
    pCallable(t),
    pfunc( [](void* pv, void* pv2)->int {
      return (*static_cast<T*>(pv))(pv2);
    } )
  {}
};

Callables cbs;
std::array< helper, 2 > arr{ &cbs.foo, &cbs.bar };

Now, you can iterate over the contents of arr and invoke each one.
Zero heap allocation, no wasted space, etc.
It does add another level of indirection.

Hi Adam, first of all: thank you very much for the detailed answer! Unfortunately, I think your solution (std::variant<lambda1_t, lambda2_t, ...>) does not work for me, because the lambda closure types are not available in the scope where I need to declare the array type (e.g. global scope).
To give you some context:
The callable array is used as a ring buffer in a command queue. Commands are enqueued by multiple threads in some function, and executed by (possibly) a different thread. The scope of the site of callable creation is completely different from where the callable is invoked.

@breiters When you enqueue, where are the parameters stored?  If the local scope ends before the calling happens, the parameters have to live somewhere, and you have ruled out dynamic allocation, and you seem to want a possibly unlimited number of parameters bound...  Second, you are now using a queue instead of an array?  "using a C-style solution with a custom data type per callable, containing the function pointer and bound parameters" - if we don't have the callable data at global scope, this "solution" isn't a solution?

"the lambda closure types are not available in the scope where I need to declare the array type" - then you are stuck because the array type doesn't know the size of the callables, so it doesn't know how much memory to reserve to avoid dynamic allocation. Which means that you're basically reinventing std::function. (Either that, or you declare a set maximum size and force a compiler error if somebody tries to use something bigger.)

@RaymondChen I mean, if the OP can store the parameters somewhere different than the array, that is another option.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont The number / size of the parameters is limited. The parameter values may change each time a command is enqueued. Thus, the actual values need to be stored alongside the callable. I am using an array as ring buffer of a bounded-size queue. The C-style solution works because each bound parameter value gets stored to a data member of some custom callable struct, which implements operator(). I think I can't avoid storing the parameter values in the callable. By the way: the std::function solution works out-of-the-box, but requires dynamic memory.

I must be missing it, where is the C-style solution? You can create your own std::function variant that refuses to do dynamic allocation (by setting a cap on sizeof(callable)). You can find an example in wistd:::function.

@RaymondChen Yes that is one of the problems. I also thought about having some kind of lambda factory which returns the type of the required lambda, but also performs the enqueue operation. This way I could get the lambda type with decltype(lambda_factory(...)) from outside of the function where the lambda/callable is required (enqueued). std::bind(...) seems to do what I need, but for some reason, it is not assignable and thus I can't move it into the array. Edit: thank you for pointing me to this link! I will definitely try.

@breiters std::bind isn't what you want.  Its type is not the same from one call of the function to another; it is a template function with a non-uniform return type, not a function.  (the size of the type returned is not constant among other details)

World's simplest non-allocating function.
// base signature of the template:
template<class Sig, std::size_t Buffer=sizeof( void(*)() ) * 4>
struct func;

// This stores the type erasure, a manual vtable.  The signature-
// unrelated portion:
struct base_func_vtable {
  void(*copy_ctor)(void* dest, void const*) = 0;
  void(*move_ctor)(void* dest, void*) = 0;
  void(*dtor)(void*) = 0;

  template<class T>
  static constexpr base_func_vtable create() {
    return {
      // copy_ctor
      +[](void* dest, void const* src){
        new(dest) T( *(T const*)src );
      },
      // move_ctor
      +[](void* dest, void* src){
        new(dest) T( std::move(*(T const*)src) );
      },
      // dtor
      +[](void* obj){
        ((T*)obj)->~T();
      }
    };
  }
};
// the signature-dependent part of the vtable (namely, invoke):
template<class R, class...Args>
struct func_vtable:base_func_vtable {
  R(*invoke)(void const* self, Args&&...args) = 0;

  template<class T>
  static constexpr func_vtable create() {
    func_vtable retval;
    (base_func_vtable&)retval = base_func_vtable::create<T>();
    retval.invoke = +[](void const* self, Args&&...args)->R {
      return (*(T const*)self)( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
    };
    return retval;
  }

  // get a global pointer to a unique vtable in static memory
  template<class T>
  static /*constexpr*/ func_vtable const* get() {
    static auto vtable = create<T>();
    return &vtable;
  }
};


template<class R, class...Args, std::size_t Sz>
struct func<R(Args...), Sz> {
  // the factory constructor.  Lambdas go through here:
  template<class F, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<func, std::decay_t<F>>, bool> = true >
  func(F&& f):
    vtable( func_vtable<R, Args...>::template get<std::decay_t<F>>() )
  {
    static_assert(sizeof(F) <= sizeof(buffer));
    new((void*)buffer) std::decay_t<F>( std::forward<F>(f) );
  }
  // copy ctor.  Can handle empty rhs:
  func(func const& o):
    vtable(o.vtable)
  {
    if (vtable)
      vtable->copy_ctor(buffer, o.buffer);
  }
  // move ctor.  Can handle empty rhs:
  func(func&& o):
    vtable(o.vtable)
  {
    if (vtable)
      vtable->move_ctor(buffer, o.buffer);
  }
  // handling empty func case:
  explicit operator bool() const { return vtable != nullptr; }
  func() {}
  func(std::nullptr_t) {}

  // a good idea would be to add generic function pointer that somehow forwards
  // to the template class F ctor above, but also checks for null.

  // assignment uses the copy_ctor:
  func& operator=(func const& o) & {
    if (this == std::addressof(o))
      return *this;
    if (vtable)
      vtable->dtor(buffer);
    vtable = o.vtable;
    if (vtable)
      vtable->copy_ctor(buffer, o.buffer);
    return *this;
  }
  // move-assignment uses the move_ctor:
  func& operator=(func && o) & {
    if (this == std::addressof(o))
      return *this;
    if (vtable)
      vtable->dtor(buffer);
    vtable = o.vtable;
    if (vtable)
      vtable->move_ctor(buffer, o.buffer);
    return *this;
  }

  // invoking:
  R operator()(Args...args){
    return vtable->invoke(buffer, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  ~func() {
    if (vtable)
      vtable->dtor(buffer);
  }
private:
  // state.  We store a manual table of operations - a vtable - then
  // a block of generic memory.
  func_vtable<R, Args...> const* vtable = nullptr;
  char buffer[Sz];
};

This assumes the underlying objects need to support both copy and move; simply remove the func const& and the copy_ctor to make it support move-only callables.
Use it like std::function.  Tweak the Sz field to get it big enough for the lambdas you want to store.
Designed to be low-C++-standard compatible.  You can clean up the enable_if_t in a more modern version (use requires), as well as a few other tweaks.
Live example.

@Adam Thanks for your help and also the Godbolt example. It took me a while to understand this code, and I've learned some things. The func template is basically exactly what I need. Since this is my first question on StackOverflow, let me ask: which answer of yours should I accept? (1) solves the original problem statement, (2) solves a different, more specific problem in my opinion.

@breiters I dunno, I honestly don't care?  :)  I only made 2 answers because they are quite different (in my opinion).  The checkmark belongs to the person who asked the original question; SO will even not put the checkmark answer at the top if it decides the other answers are more relevant.  func is a horrible name for this btw.  I intended it as a reasonably readable version of what is going on within a std::function type class.  It isn't quite library worthy; I, for example, ignore alignment requirements.  Also a copy_assign in the vtable can add efficiency.

Well, the code shows how one can, in principle, implement it in such a way that even I (not a C++ fluent) can understand it after a while. It doesn't need to be perfect for this purpose. Thanks everyone. Marking (1) as accepted answer since it answers the question as stated originally.
